# Very Slow Updates on tables

Tags: azure-synapse

We are reproducing an existing solution in Azure DWH (Now Synapse) It loads incremental data and has a flag that is set to 0 to indicate the data needs to be "processed" into the DIMS and FACTS. Once processed the tables are added to a list that needs to be reset.

A maintenance job in the evening runs through the list and runs

```
UPDATE xxxx SET FLAG_COLUMN = 1 WHERE FLAG_COLUMN = 0
```

I'm getting really variable performance on this. 1.8bn row tables update in 5m, smaller 700m row tables are taking approaching an hour. Almost all the tables are COLUMN STORES. I have tried simplifying the UPDATE to

```
UPDATE xxxx SET FLAG_COLUMN = 1
```

I would expect this to be pretty quick for a column store as it's flushing the entire column but this seems to make no meaningful difference between column stores and heaps. There are 1800 tables that need to be reset every day. Running these 40 at a time is still going to run to 2-3+ hrs for a reset at the best speeds I have achieved. For the queries that are crawling it's unachievable in a day.

All this is running while the environment is quiet so it's not an issue with other queries interfering. I haven't explored altering the resource class as yet but the account it's running under is StaticRC40 and seems to run the ADF driven loads way way faster than these updated at this level of parallelism (in terms of queries).

Has anyone got any advice? ideas of other things I might try? The tables vary in size form low 100k to 18bn rows (thankfully most are in the sub 10m range) we're running the instance at scale DW3000c and it's quick enough on most other stuff we run.

These relatively simple UPDATES just seem to be terminally sub optimal. Any advice would be genuinely appreciated

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be pretty straight forward. We weren't reproducing the existing behavior.

In the migration there are approx. 1800 ODS tables, all of them have the ROW_SENT_TO_EDW flag but a huge number of them have never had this flag set so all the rows are 0. The “slow” tables were the ones where all the rows were 0 so the update was against many hundreds of millions of billions of rows. This confirms it’s the TRANSACTION logging for the UPDATE that's the root cause of the slow and the randomness was to do with how many rows we were having to update. (I still don't understand why setting the entire column = 0 for a COLUMNSTORE INDEX table isn't super fast)

Running some analysis and looking at using HEAPS instead of CLUSTERED COLUMN INDEX tables. This was all at 3000C DWU

**Impact of HEAP versus CCI**

CCI table (update all 1.8bn rows)

```
-- (staticrc40) 1hr 43m 47s
-- (largerc)   1hr  4m 11s
```

HEAP table (update all 1.8bn rows)

```
-- (staticrc40) 2hr 13m 5s
-- (largerc)        48m 47s
```

**CTAS the entire table out just switching the column value**

CTAS is Microsofts answer to everything

CCI
-- (staticrc40) 56m

HEAP
-- (staticrc40) 1h 35m

Yes it’s faster than updating the entire table but still too slow for us

**Impact of resource class**

CCI table updating 14m rows of 1.8bn (smallrc typical user)

```
-- (staticrc40)  1m 30s
-- (smallrc)     1m 40s
```

CCI table with fresh STATS on the ROW_SENT_TO_EDW column before flipping the 0 to 1

```
-- (staticrc40) 1m 6s
-- (smallrc)    1m 8s
```

HEAP table updating 14m rows of 1.8bn (smallrc typical user)

```
-- (staticrc40)  30s
-- (smallrc)     37s
```

HEAP table with fresh STATS on the ROW_SENT_TO_EDW column before flipping the 0 to 1

```
-- (staticrc40) 25s
-- (smallrc)    25s
```

So it looks like HEAPS perform better than CCI in this particular instance and resource classes do make a difference but not as much as you might think (the storage operations and transaction logging are obviously the critical factors)

**Sneaky Full table Update**

Finally, the full table changes are obviously enormous and sub optimal. So we decided to look at dropping the column entirely and the adding it back in with a default

You have to find the any stats and drop those before you can drop the column
Dropping the column takes 15s on CCI and 20s on HEAP

Adding it back in with a default on CCI takes 29s

On HEAP it takes 20s (shocked by this as I expected the page writes to take a huge amount of time but it obviously does something clever under the covers)

You have to drop the default constraint straight away otherwise you won’t be able to drop the column again and also put the stats back on. (this often takes 20s)

But for both types of tables this method is super super fast compared to a full table update

SQL for this drop and add looks like this

```
-- get the name of the stat to drop
SELECT
              t.[name]                            AS [table_name]
              , s.[name]                          AS [table_schema_name]
              , c.[name]                          AS [column_name]
              , c.[column_id]                     AS [column_id]
              , t.[object_id]                     AS [object_id]
              ,st.[name]    As stats_name
              , ROW_NUMBER()
                     OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))    AS [seq_nmbr]
       FROM
              sys.tables t
              JOIN sys.schemas s ON  t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
              JOIN sys.columns c ON  t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
              INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns l ON  l.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                     AND l.[column_id] = c.[column_id]
                     AND l.[stats_column_id] = 1
              INNER JOIN sys.stats st
                     ON  t.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
                     and l.stats_id = st.stats_id
WHERE t.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('BKP.SRC_xxx')

DROP STATISTICS BKP.SRC_xxx._WA_Sys_0000000E_2CEA8251

-- now alter the actual table
ALTER TABLE BKP.SRC_xxx 
DROP COLUMN ROW_SENT_TO_EDW
-- 13s

ALTER TABLE BKP.SRC_xxx 
       ADD ROW_SENT_TO_EDW INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
-- 1s  


-- find the constraint
SELECT t.[name] AS Table_Name, 
              c.[name] AS Column_Name,
              dc.[name] as DefaultConstraintName
FROM   sys.tables t 
                     INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
                           ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id] 
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc
                           ON  t.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id
                           AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
WHERE  t.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('BKP.SRC_xxx')
       AND c.[name] = 'ROW_SENT_TO_EDW'

-- drop the constraint
ALTER TABLE BKP.SRC_xxx DROP CONSTRAINT [Cnstr_7183c5bec657448da3475af85110123a]
--  18s

-- create stats
CREATE STATISTICS [thingy] ON BKP.SRC_xxx([ROW_SENT_TO_EDW])
--  9s
```

Comment: Updates on columnstore have always been slow.  I was thinking about an append-only pattern where you never update the columnstore, you simply *append* a record to a tracking table, eg with the table name, primary key and current value and a datestamp.  You can then lookup the *current* value any time and delete historical values at a time where performance is less critical.  What do you think?

Comment: Yeah that’s how it should be written but we’re migrating an existing solution and there’s 500k+ lines of code running on this thing. We can’t go changing the data structures as too many business processes hook into these tables and use these very columns. :-( I must have done something very bad in a previous life...

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same pattern of having a BIT column to identify changed/inserted ODS records which should trigger a dimension update.

I didn't specifically test CCI on the source tables, I used heap as they were all 10M row less. However, I did find that it was essential to have a non-clustered index on the BIT column and to use CONVERT(BIT... so that the index could be used. 0 or 1 in a where clause  without a CONVERT/CAST comes across as an INT and can block the ability to use the NCI. This had a huge impact on the performance to both update the dims based on the flag column and the update operation.

UPDATE src_table
SET processed_flag = 1
where processed_flag = CONVERT(BIT, 0)

BTW - totally agree with the sentiment that CTAS is too often the answer to everything when it's not always practical and is often a slower operation simply due to having to copy so much data.